# Limit SOQL query results from child clause

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex, soql

Hopefully this will be easy to answer:

```
select name, id, description, isactive, productcode, imageurl__c, (select name, id, unitprice,Must_Override_Price__c, Is_Taxable__c from PricebookEntries where pricebook2id =: pbe.id) from product2
```

How do I prevent the product2 records that have no child pricebookentry records from being queried?

So lets say I have 10 products, but only two match the WHERE clause.  I only want those two to show up so I'm not wasting resources/rows.

Answer (score 1):

Perform the query relationship in reverse. You can still get all the required Product2 fields, and you will only get results for existing PricebookEntry records.

E.g.

```
select Id, Name, Pricebook2Id, Product2Id, UnitPrice, IsActive, UseStandardPrice, 
       ProductCode, IsDeleted, 
       Product2.Id, Product2.Name 
from PricebookEntry
where pricebook2id = :pbe.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the query in reverse as mentioned in the Daniel's comment or try putting where condition in the top query as well

```
select name, id, description, isactive, productcode, imageurl__c,
  (select name, id, unitprice,Must_Override_Price__c, Is_Taxable__c 
     from PricebookEntries 
   where pricebook2id =: pbe.id) 
from product2
where Id IN (select Product2Id 
              from PricebookEntries 
             where pricebook2id =: pbe.id)
```